# Constraints on the moments of a bounded probability distribution

Tags: distributions, moments, bounds, constraint

Consider a probability distribution with support on $[0,1]$. Suppose the first $n$ raw moments $m_1,...,m_n$ are given. What are the constraints on the $(n+1)^\text{th}$ moment? Obviously we have the loose bounds $0\leq m_{n+1}\leq 1$. Better yet, using the monotonicity of moments, we have that $m_{n+1}\geq m_n^{(n+1)/n}$, which I don't know to be tight or loose.

I am looking for tight bounds for $m_{n+1}$, lower and upper, if they are known.

Comment: This question and its answers seem very relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2354090/existence-of-random-variable-given-first-k-moments